# Netbeans Java Web Application wont deploy after moving classes to package

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, web-applications

I just moved all my java classes to a package (SSP) as I had them inside the default package uo to that point and now my application wont deploy to tomcat anymore....

I use:

- Netbeans 8.0.2
- Tomcat 8.0.28
- PostgreSQL 9.4

I tried the following without any change:

- deleted Netbeans Cache at C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache
- clean and build project
- shutdown tomcat and restarted it

Error (Tomcat Log):

```
03-Dec-2015 09:53:13.330 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class SSP.Startup  java.lang.NullPointerException
at SSP.Load_config.getPropValues_db_user_pw(Load_config.java:89)
at SSP.Roles_rights.get_roles_rights(Roles_rights.java:52)
at SSP.Roles_rights.getInstance(Roles_rights.java:35)
at SSP.Startup.contextInitialized(Startup.java:21)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4738)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5181)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:586)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:460)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1586)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1460)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:906)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:344)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Error Netbeans debug:

```
FAIL - Deployed application at context path /Self-Service-Portal but context failed to start
D:\Dropbox\Bachelor\Java Projects\Self-Service-Portal\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1157: The module has not been deployed.
```

The following code snippets are the classes named in the tomcat log:

SSP.Load_config.getPropValues_db_user_pw(Load_config.java:89)

```
72: public String getPropValues_db_user_pw() throws IOException {
73:    try {
74:        Properties prop = new Properties();
75:        String propFileName = "db_settings.properties";
76:        inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);
77
78:        if (inputStream != null) {
79:            prop.load(inputStream);
80:        } else {
81:            throw new FileNotFoundException("property file '" + propFileName + "' not found in the classpath");
82:        }
83:        
84:        // compose result string (ip:port)
85:        result = prop.getProperty("db_passwd");
86:    } catch (Exception e) {
87:            System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
88:    } finally {
89:        if (inputStream != null) {
90:            inputStream.close();
91:        }
92:    }
93:    return result;
94: }
```

SSP.Roles_rights.get_roles_rights(Roles_rights.java:52)

```
40: public void get_roles_rights(){
41:
42:    // Get roles & rigths from db
43:    // variables
44:    JDBCConnection database_connection = null;
45:    ResultSet m_ResultSet = null;
46:
47:    // load standard db-user from config file
48:    Load_config properties = new Load_config();
49:
50:    // connect to postgreSQL Database
51:    try {
52:        database_connection = new JDBCConnection("Self-Service-Portal", properties.getPropValues_db_user(), properties.getPropValues_db_user_pw());
53:    } catch (IOException ex) {
54:        Logger.getLogger(User_management.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
55:    }
       .......
114: }
```

SSP.Roles_rights.getInstance(Roles_rights.java:35)

```
24:  public class Roles_rights {
25:     
26:     public List<List<Integer>> oe_fac_roles_rights = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(4);
27: 
28:     private static Roles_rights instance = null;
29:     private Roles_rights() {
30:       // Exists only to defeat instantiation.
31:     }
32:     public static Roles_rights getInstance() {
33:         if(instance == null) {
34:             instance = new Roles_rights();
35:             instance.get_roles_rights();
36:         }
37:         return instance;
38:     }
39:    
40:     public void get_roles_rights(){ 
        ......
114:    }
115: }
```

SSP.Startup.contextInitialized(Startup.java:21)

```
16: public class Startup implements javax.servlet.ServletContextListener {
17:    
18:    @Override
19:    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
20:        // create singleton object to get all roles/rights from db
21:        Roles_rights tmp = Roles_rights.getInstance();
22:    }
23:
24:    @Override
25:    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
26:        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
27:    }
28: }
```

Just in case i put up some more information:

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="Self-Service-Portal" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>SSP.Login</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Usermode</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>SSP.Usermode</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Echo_usermode</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>SSP.Echo_usermode</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>User_management</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>SSP.User_management</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/portal.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Usermode</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/usermode/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Echo_usermode</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/echo_usermode</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>User_management</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/user_management/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<listener>
    <listener-class>SSP.Startup</listener-class>
</listener>
```

My project structure

[image: My project structure]

Furthermore Netbeans shows me an error for the web.xml:

```
cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'web-app'
```

as this did show before and never caused problems I dont know if this is maybe the cause

Does any1 have an idea why my application wont deploy just because my classes are now inside package SSP and not in default package anymore since I adjusted the package change inside web.xml??

greetings
Alkahna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try closing your inputstream even though it's null. Consider moving to try-with-resource instead. Or at least check inputStream to be `!= null` before closing it.

```
73:    try {
76:        inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);
77
78:        if (inputStream != null) {
80:        } else {
82:        }
83:        
88:    } finally {
89:            inputStream.close(); //Might be null -> cause of your error
90:    }
```

As for the reason why that's null: Check if the properties file was deployed to where you think it should have been. Try using `getClass().getResourceAsStream()` instead of using the classloader method. Try using absolute path `/SSP/db_settings.properties`.

Comment: I added the null check & changed from `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()` to `getClass()getResourceAsStream(propFileName)` and now it works fine, thanks a lot :)

Comment: it turns out that the null check is not nessecary but the change from `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()` to `getClass()getResourceAsStream(propFileName)` did solve this error

Comment: The nullcheck was what created the visible error. Which is a good thing, because otherwise your question might have been "my database connection does not work" :-)

Comment: I just dont get why it worked when all classes were inside the default package and the error only occurs when classes are not in default package